# Java Swing Debugging with IDEA - ctrl-shift-F1, not dumping AWT component hierarchy

Tags: java, swing

This trick doesn't seems to dump the AWT component hierarchy to the console. I pressed `ctrl-shift-F1` while the focus is on a Swing component (I hope by focus we mean that is the component we see on our screen). And i went back and checked my intellij console nothing is there. Please help me if i am doing anything wrong.

I am using **Intellij IDEA 10.5 Community Edition**. I hope this won't be the issue.

Comment: Could you use a newer version of IntelliJ IDEA?  10.5 hasn't been supported in years.

Comment: @Makoto I took your advice and just tried it with 14.1.4 (Community Edition) now. But still it doesn't seems to work.

Comment: Ctrl-Shift-F1 is a feature of AWT, not IntelliJ IDEA, so it doesn't matter which version of IntelliJ IDEA you use. Also note that AWT is not Swing, and a normal Swing application does not have any AWT components, so there is nothing to dump.

Comment: @yole Yes , I understand that and my application is using AWT.

Answer (score 2):

As of Java 9, the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> shortcut is disabled by default. To enable it, pass `-Dsun.awt.nativedebug=true -Dawtdebug.on=true` to your app.